# Javascript regex to remove character and number from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have this String that I need to remove the underscore number from all words that contain them.

```
"View":{"Name":"Untitled-4","Image_1":{"BackgroundImage":"Image.png","Position":[0,0],"Width":320,"Height":480},"Button_1":{"BackgroundImage":"ButtonTop.png","Position":[61,83],"Width":217,"Height":58},"Button_2":{"BackgroundImage":"ButtonBottom.png","Position":[81,114],"Width":205,"Height":73},"TextField_1":{"BackgroundImage":"TextFieldLogin.png","Position":[102,336],"Width":189,"Height":31},"Label_1":{"Position":[137,100],"Width":54,"Height":20,"Text":"HiRob","FontSize":18,"Color":[0,0,0,1]},"Label_2":{"Position":[43,342],"Width":72,"Height":20,"Text":"LogOut:","FontSize":18,"Color":[0,0,0,1]},"Label_3":{"Position":[115,234],"Width":126,"Height":20,"Text":"AnotherButton","FontSize":18,"Color":[0,0,0,1]}}
```

I output i am looking for is:

```
"View":{"Name":"Untitled-4","Image":{"BackgroundImage":"Image.png","Position":[0,0],"Width":320,"Height":480},"Button":{"BackgroundImage":"ButtonTop.png","Position":[61,83],"Width":217,"Height":58},"Button":{"BackgroundImage":"ButtonBottom.png","Position":[81,114],"Width":205,"Height":73},"TextField":{"BackgroundImage":"TextFieldLogin.png","Position":[102,336],"Width":189,"Height":31},"Label":{"Position":[137,100],"Width":54,"Height":20,"Text":"HiRob","FontSize":18,"Color":[0,0,0,1]},"Label":{"Position":[43,342],"Width":72,"Height":20,"Text":"LogOut:","FontSize":18,"Color":[0,0,0,1]},"Label":{"Position":[115,234],"Width":126,"Height":20,"Text":"AnotherButton","FontSize":18,"Color":[0,0,0,1]}}
```

Comment: This looks far too much like JSON. Are you sure you don't want to apply the removing only on keys?

Comment: Not only does it look like JSON, but the applied transformation will turn it into _illegal_ JSON (a JSON object cannot have duplicate keys, see RFC 4627)

Comment: This is solved below, but the reason we have the numbering on there is to keep it unique when it is used as JSON, and then we strip the numbering out when its stored as a string in a db. We cannot have it structured any other way due to some other dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
var replaced = str.replace(/_\d+/g, '')
```